# Why is meat eating sanctioned by G-d if it's potentially bad for us?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, korban, parashat-noach, parshat-devarim

In parsha Noach, G-d **ALLOWS** man to eat meat but there is no literal commandment to do so. Later, when the Mishkan and then ultimately the Beis Hamikdash are built, there are commandments for the Kohens to consume parts of the korban.

In addition, Devarim 12:20 says —
*"When the Lord, your G-d, expands your boundary, as He has spoken to you, and you say, "I will eat meat," **because your soul desires to eat meat, you may eat meat**, according to every desire of your soul."*

So it seems G-d is ok with man eating meat within the restrictions of kashrut if man so desires and the Kohanim are expected to consume it. But in these times, scientists and nutritionists are telling us that eating meat, red meat in particular, is not healthy.

**So the question: *Why does Hashem sanction the eating of meat if it's generally unhealthy for us?***

Comment: Why would I think that all unhealthy things are forbidden?

Comment: @LN6595 — Of course there are countless unhealthy things available to us that we can choose to partake of or not, but I'm focusing on meat eating because an animal must be killed and the Torah spends a goodly amount of time discussing it. It's not like smoking or gambling which are choices as well.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108745/19691)?

Answer (score 2):

In moderation meat isn't bad for you.

In [this article](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/meat-good-or-bad#bottom-line) on the issue, the bottom line is:

*Unprocessed and properly cooked meat has many nutrients and may have some health benefits. If you enjoy eating meat, there is no compelling health or nutritional reason to stop.*

God wants us to enjoy in a reasonable fashion!

Comment: Interestingly we have prohibitions parallel to the unhealthy aspects of meat (fatty/Cheilev, preserved/Notar and undercooked/Pesach)

Comment: Realize most modern Western people will way overestimate what this healthy moderation is. If you have some meat only on Jewish holidays, then you'll indeed be eating it in moderation.